# Unable to Extract .apk files from Bluestacks app player using adb

Tags: android, bluestacks

I'm trying to extract .apk files of my apps installed from blue stacks player using adb .I am successful in getting the .apk's of files that are present in the location    "/system/app".  Below is the command that i gave from my command line

```
 adb pull /system/app C:\xyz\ffff
```

However,When i am trying to get the .apk of the apps that are present in the location "/data/app" it says

```
"0 files pulled"
```

However,I'm pretty much sure it has got over 10 apps.

Any help would be highly helpful

Comment: Do you want to move apk from bluestack to pc folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Download 'apkextractor' app from playstore and install it in your bluetack, This application can extract the applications installed in bluestack
2.To access this .apk files you need any filemanager, And go to extractedApk directory
3.To move apk files from bluestack to pc folder, **Move the .apk files from  'extractedApk' to 'windows/pictures' folder**

This screenshot will help you

[image]

Answer (score 2):

In the latest versions of Android, APKs are no longer simply stored in the `/data/app` folder.

To get the list of installed packages (and their paths) run the following:

```
adb shell pm list packages -f
```

This will show you packages and paths to the APKs. Like this:

```
package:/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk=com.android.chrome
```

Here, you can see the APK resides at `/data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk`

Running `adb pull /data/app/com.android.chrome-2/base.apk` works.

You need to do this for each APK shown in the package list. On non-rooted devices, you cannot search for APKs in the `/data/app` folder because `adb` does not have permission to view the contents of folders in this location.